# how to share a variable from java code with some javascript functions

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine

I have a scenario where I have to invoke some functions using XML RPC. As my web app is on Google App Engine and the Apache XML RPC Library for Java is not fully supported by App Engine, I thought that I should store the login/access credentials with the help of java code, and then the javascript code should pick up those credentials (maybe as session variables??) and invoke the necessary calls and obtain data.

Is the above scenario doable? How do I share a variable, ideally as a session variable, between java and javascript code?

Comment: Moving stuff to the client side because your favorite library isn't supported is likely a very bad idea - particularly if the credentials are in any way confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible!

I suggest to study this page carefully:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields

And if you have any questions just create a new question with JSNI tag.

Comment: I understand that what I want is doable... However I have a question for you- if I do set a variable in java code, and then access that using JSNI in my javascript, then will the variable's value be seen by the end user, either directly or through Javascript Console/Firebug etc? This is very important for me, as I dont want the login credentials to be exposed to the end user... thanks...

Comment: Well because your method becomes globally available to all javascript it's very possible for someone to rewrite some of the java code even after it's been obsfucated, it would take some effort but yes that is possible. On the other hand if you just hash it and unhash it later on there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: will the data be accessible even in a web app? I wont be sharing the code of the application with anyone and it will be a web application on google app engine, so my only concern here is if an end user can obtain the api credentials (that I will obtain using JSNI) from the javascript...java code rewrite should not be possible since I am working only on a web app in this scenario... Thanks

Comment: Sorry, i actually meant to rewrite some of the javascript code.
So like i said, the JSNI is open for anything. so it's possible to call that method again with new javascript and do something with the data. you need to make sure only you can use that method, or make sure even if someone calls that jsni method he won't know what to do with the data( like a hash ). But the basic user won't actually see any of the variables.